# What are the problems in my Ubuntu Installation?

Tags: 22.04

I am very new in Ubuntu world. Even though I have started it few years before but didn't continue my journey with Ubuntu. However I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and when I do sudo apt-get update I see these some issues probably. As I am not an expert I really can't understand meanings of these statements. Can anyone please let me know exactly what are the problems and how to get rid of these?

https://pastebin.com/wgbAU3bE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Apparently, you've added some non-defgault repositories that produce errors. Just remove them.

Comment: "*As I am not an expert I really can't understand meanings of these statements*" Do your part: Google the error messages, learn the meaning, and become an expert. The developers WANT you to understand the problem.